# Service Fabric cluster creation error using powershell

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I´m traying to create a service fabric cluster on azure but when I execute
the next script:

```
   #Provide the subscription Id
   $subscriptionId = 'yourSubscriptionId'

   # Certificate variables.
   $certpwd="Password#1234" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
   $certfolder="c:\mycertificates\"

   # Variables for VM admin.
   $adminuser="vmadmin"
   $adminpwd="Password#1234" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force 

   # Variables for common values
   $clusterloc="SouthCentralUS"
   $clustername = "mysfcluster"
   $groupname="mysfclustergroup"       
   $vmsku = "Standard_D2_v2"
   $vaultname = "mykeyvault"
   $subname="$clustername.$clusterloc.cloudapp.azure.com"

   # Set the number of cluster nodes. Possible values: 1, 3-99
   $clustersize=5 

   # Set the context to the subscription Id where the cluster will be created
   Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId

   # Create the Service Fabric cluster.
   New-AzServiceFabricCluster -Name $clustername -ResourceGroupName $groupname -  Location $clusterloc `
-  ClusterSize $clustersize -VmUserName $adminuser -VmPassword $adminpwd 
-  CertificateSubjectName $subname `
-  CertificatePassword $certpwd -CertificateOutputFolder $certfolder `
-  OS WindowsServer2016DatacenterwithContainers -VmSku $vmsku -KeyVaultName                                       
   $vaultname
```

the powershell console show this error:

ADVERTENCIA: Access policy is not set. No user or application have access permission to use this vault. Please use Set -AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy to set access policies.

I´m following this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-quickstart-containers#feedback

```
# Create the Service Fabric cluster.
   New-AzServiceFabricCluster -Name $clustername -ResourceGroupName $groupname -  Location $clusterloc `
-  ClusterSize $clustersize -VmUserName $adminuser -VmPassword $adminpwd 
-  CertificateSubjectName $subname `
-  CertificatePassword $certpwd -CertificateOutputFolder $certfolder `
-  OS WindowsServer2016DatacenterwithContainers -VmSku $vmsku -KeyVaultName                                       
   $vaultname
```

ADVERTENCIA: Access policy is not set. No user or application have access permission to use this vault. Please use Set -AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy to set access policies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're running into an existing [issue](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/910).
The workaround is to manually define the Key Vault access policy to allow the Resource Manager to access the Key Vault during template deployment.

Comment: Could you help me with that?

Comment: Try this: `Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName $vaultName -EnabledForDeployment`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It Works.

Comment: always happy to help